Paysafe Checkout updates for 3DS compliance
I need to update a Paysafe Checkout integration due to a change in requirements from Visa[1].  From the suggested changes I can see that I have to add email/phone/cellphone values to a profile object on the setup options, but the API documentation does not detail any profile properties, so I'm at a loss as to what to do about this.  Has anyone else had to deal with this that could offer some insights?
FWIW here's a code snippet of the JS code from the place I think I need to add the profile data.  Note: the code currently works without the profile data, so I can't tell if just adding the profile data to paymentData has any effect at all :-/
const paymentData = {
    amount: amount,
    currency: 'GBP',
    accounts:{
        CC: accountNumber
    },
    billingAddress:{
        country: "GB",
        zip: postcode,
        state: state,
        city: city,
        street: address,
    },
    environment: 'TEST',
    companyName: 'myco',
    buttonColor: '#121212',
    imageUrl: 'https://myco.com/img/logo.jpg', 
    holderName: '',
    displayPaymentMethods: ['Cards'],
    threeDS: {
        useThreeDSecureVersion2: true
    }
};
const payeeData={
    amount,
    address,
    city,
    state,
    postcode,
    reference
};
const token = GetToken();
paysafe.checkout.setup(
    token,
    paymentData,
    function (instance, error, result) {
        postPaymentProcessing(payeeData, instance, error, result);
    },
    function(stage){
        console.log('closed at payment stage: ' + stage);
    }
);

[1] https://go.pardot.com/webmail/365931/1644206923/c2913a61471857eeea22a44effc737a3815c5cce267486bd0a60c8173b57b599
[2] https://developer.paysafe.com/en/api-docs/client-side-sdks/paysafe-checkout-powered-by-cards-api/setup-function/
